# Is the set of even integers closed under this metric

Tags: general-topology

Let $d: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $p$ be an odd prime.

let $d$ be defined via

$$d(m,n)=0 \space \text{if $m=n$}$$

and

$$d(m,n)=\frac{1}{r+1} \space \text{if $m \neq n$}$$

where $r \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ is such that $p^r \mid m-n$ but $p^{r+1}\nmid m-n$.

Prove or disprove that the set

$$2 \mathbb{Z}:=\{...,-4,-2,0,2,4,...\}$$

is closed in $\mathbb{Z}$. I know that the difference of two evens is again even and the difference of two odds is even. So if considering the odd integers, then for any two odd integers $m,n$ we have

$$d(m,n)=\frac{1}{0+1}=1$$

this is because if $p$ is odd then only $p^0 \mid m-n$.

so we cannot make the distance arbitrarily small thus the odds cannot be open and thus the evens are not closed?

Comment: Note that $3^1\mid9-3$.

Comment: aha good point! @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+p^n=1$. But each number of the form $1+p^n$ is even, whereas $1$ is odd. So, the set of even integers is not closed.

Comment: Aha so it doesn't contain all its own limit points, cannot be closed!

Comment: Question, how does the limit of $1+p^n$ =$1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Furthermore, $1+p^n$ doesn't include all the even integers, does this suffices to showing the set of all even integers is not closed?

Comment: You have $d(1+p^n,1)=\frac1{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}=0$.

Comment: And what I did shows that there is a sequence of even integers that converges to a non-even integer. If the set of even integers was closed, every convergent sequence of even integer would converge to an even integer.

Comment: It's like showing that $(0,2)$ is not closed with respect to the usual distance. It is enough to show that each $\frac1n$ (with $n\in\Bbb N$) belongs to $(0,2)$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0\notin(0,2)$. I did not have to use *all* elements of $(0,2)$ to prove this.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. And for the limit I forgot to invoke my metric!! thanks!!

Comment: I was waiting for it to allow me to, thanks !